# Firebase rules: Disable writing for username

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I created a chat app using Firebase, and sometimes chat users flooding the champ and I want to block him.

I created my block method to set the following:

```
chat_blocks/USERNAME_TO_BLOCK:true
```

and my rules:

```
".write": "!root.child('chat_blocks/'+newData.child('username').val()).exists()"
```

But it blocked everyone.

My structure is simple as:

```
chat_messages
-$key 
-- username
-- message

chat_messages/--list of messages
```

Comment: Adding your current database tree might be helpful.

Comment: @EmilDavid Sorry forgot about it. It's the simplest, I added the structure

Comment: First of, do you know that in Firebase rules, a rule declared at a parent node is applied to all of its children?

Comment: Yep @EmilDavid I did post only the relevant code. I updated with the full rules

Comment: I'm not the best with FrB rules but I'll take a jab at it. Why not get rid of the validate and have your write as `.write: newData.child('username').val() != 'BAN_THIS_USER'`

Comment: Please let me know if it doesn't work because I have another idea I can swing by you if you're open to different suggestions on resolving your issue

Comment: It didn't.I  already tried it. Anyway see my updated question I made some improvements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging and found two solutions.

**1. Set a ban on a user**

Consider adding a `bannedFor` node under your `users` tree. Then all you would have to do is go to your `users` node and make sure that info doesn't exist and give them access to both `.read` and `.write`

```
users
  $uid
    "bannedUntil": 1486599300
```

Now when it comes to your rules, it would look something like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "!data.child('bannedUntil').exists() || data.child('bannedUntil').val() < now"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Set a message rate**

Limit the amount of messages a user can send in a certain time slot. I found a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/VBmA5/) along with the [rules](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/00a4ec40df1552d01c7f) for this solution.

> Throttle messages to no more than one every 5,000 milliseconds

PS: I know this does not necessarily solve your current issue, but it provides alternate resolutions.

Comment: This is a great alternative. My users are stored in my server side and not in my firebase, that's why it's not currently relevant.